# Could someone who has control over electricity and wind manipulate the force of magnetism/electromagnetism?

Tags: science-based, magic

I plan on incorporating the power of magnetism/electromagnetism into my magic system.
The thing is I already have the power to manipulate electricity and wind (in my magic system electricity and wind are related in lore and symbolic reasons) as their own category.

With that being the case, would having magnetism/electromagnetism be its own power separate from electricity be redundant and incorrect?
Does being able to control electricity necessitate magnetism in some way, shape, or form?

Sorry if this a stupid question btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Electromagnetism is an effect of special relativity pretaining to the motions of electrons. Basically any even slightly refined control over electricity is capable of creating magnetic fields too. Veritasium has a great video on this. https://youtu.be/1TKSfAkWWN0

Answer (score 2):

Depends how your system is structured. If it has "techniques" then you could say that people who know a lot about electromagnetism can refine their electrical power into something more precise, controlling magnetism and such.

If you've ever watched Avatar the last airbender, think of electromagnetic manipulation like you would lightning bending or blood bending, they come from fire and water and are connected to their core element, but are more so minor techniques than an element of their own.

That's how I handle electromagnetic powers in my world, an electrical scientist has great knowledge on how electromagnetism works and can use his lightning magic in ways the others can't.

Answer (score 1):

Magnetism is caused by electrons and protons mostly being near objects and exerting an electromagnetic force on them. It's a constant effect in some materials because of where the electrons and protons are, but it's the same underlying mechanics as electromagnetism.

If you can control electricity you can already move electrons or ions. That implies you have some ability to simulate magnetic effects.

It's worth considering what the underlying difference is. If you can magically move electrons, why can't you make materials more magnetic, or put a powerful charge in objects? Perhaps magical electromagnetism lets you make electrons and protons have a larger charge, so they can pull and tug things harder, but doesn't give you fine control over the movement of electrons and protons and ions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If I make electrons go in a loop, I've created a magnet. If I shake a bunch of electrons up and down, I've created an electromagnet wave.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes or No

While complex, the answer is yes to both.

### The Decisions

The one is that while these magicians can use both power or just elctro-magnatism, a good word for a single discipline, but you have to ask how much power they have and their control over it. It would be understandable if a weaker mage had to pick one and specialize.

### Shape and Form

These, among others, are the variable that effects the reaction. Mental martial arts for electro-magnatism. Plus, magnetic powers would well with metal weapons.

*Lastly, you have a lot of options for whatever works for your story and do that. Some settings only have lightning or metal, others both without electro-magnatism at all.*